# Post value that is outside of form

Tags: html, forms, post

I am writing a form, and I want to be able to post a value that is inside the form, as well as get a string that is outside of the form. Here is my code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">A Honey of a Saison</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
        <img class="pull-left" style="padding-right: 5px" src="images\beer pics\A Honey of A Siason.jpg"/>
            <p>
                Name: A Honey of a Saison<br>
                By: Boulder Beer / Wilderness Pub<br>
                Style: Belgian Strong Pale Ale<br>
                ABV: 11.50%<br><br>
                Price: $5.99
            </p>
            <p>
                Description: <br> Pours a hazed bronze color and light white foam and lace.
                Aroma of malty sugar, Belgian yeast, honey sweetness. In the taste, mild herbal bitterness,
                sweet malt notes, honey, as advertised, and booze. There are hints of herb, mint, and pepper.
                Mostly sweet, some alcohol is noticed, but tastes pretty good. Medium bodied, well carbonated,
                loose, smooth feel with a low level of heat. Overall, this was a big sweet saison, as you would
                expect from such a name.
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form method="post">
            <label for="amount">Amount</label>
            <input type="number" name="amount" min="0" max="12" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end of myModal -->
```

I am trying to post amount and the title of the modal with id="myModalLabel (in this case A Honey of a Saison)

Comment: I'm not sure if you are able, but i believe you'll have to use javascript for that...

Comment: use hidden input field :)

Answer (score 0):

Your only realistic options are:

- Move the field you need within the form
- On submit, use JavaScript to grab the value you need and copy it into a hidden input that is inside the form